Inventor builds "flying doughnut" time machine
Been remembering a children's/YA Sci-fi novel I read years back and wanted to identify.
This lady inventor built a time machine that was described in the book as a flying doughnut and I think it opened with her and her two kids viewing some dinosaurs.
One of the kids, a boy, told a friend about the time machine who promptly sold the story to a reporter in exchange for 50 "ecu" which was the currency in the maybe near future setting and then the inventor's home is swarmed by the media.
The climax of the story was a pack of neo-Nazis showing up and demanding the inventor bring Hitler to the present, though like any good "patriot" they don't speak any language other than English.
After dispensing with the neo-Nazis by some means I don't recall the inventor destroys the machine by sending it back in time and dumping it in Mt Vesuvius, the book ends with the family speculating that they may have inadvertently caused the eruption that destroyed Pompeii.

In passing, the ECU did exist as a unit of account (no actual notes or coins) as a predecessor of the Euro (€). Wikipedia page.

Nazis and dinosaurs: the two staples of time travel stories.

@TripeHound:  The écu was also a coin in pre-revolutionary France.  But you're probably right that the author was referring to the ECU.

Probably Timesnatch (1994) by Robert Swindells.
Calling the ship a "doughnut:"

Kizzy gazed at her mother's machine — a machine which could vanish and reappear like something in a magic show. It reminded her of an enormous doughnut. In fact, she'd christened it 'the Doughnut' without telling the other two. 'It's absolutely fantastic, Mum,' she breathed. 'What will you call it?'

Selling information to a journalist:

Bilbo shook his head. The journalist sighed, produced a fat wallet and counted out some notes which he folded and passed across the table. 'There you go — there's fifty E there. That's for the information you've given me, and for your discretion. Know what discretion means, do you?'

Dealing with Nazis:

'They're Nazis,' snarled Harper. 'A bunch of Nazi thugs who can't muster a decent brain between them. Take your hand off my wheel, please — we're going.'

Disposing of it in a volcano in the past:

Harper laughed. 'There are no bits, darling. I didn't destroy it in the lab. I'm not that daft. I piled all my papers into it and sent the whole caboodle into the past — two thousand years into the past — and to make absolutely sure, I dumped it in the mouth of an active volcano.' She smiled. 'So — those boys back there are searching in vain. There's nothing left but some shorted-out circuitry which might have been used for anything.'

A well-known volcano:

'Which volcano would you have chosen?' pressed Harper. 'Which name comes into your mind whenever you hear the word volcano?'
'Vesuvius,' murmured Kizzy.

The book is available to borrow at the Internet Archive.
